# rsync based on modified time

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync `rsync $source $destination`.  How do I rsync based on modified time?  I see an option for file size `--size-only` but nothing for modified time?

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Do you want to update files based on _only_ modified time? Does `--update` do what you want (check the manual)?  What do you mean by "based on modified time"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Why would you want to worry about modified time? `rsync -a` (or `rsync -t`) will propagate times to the target and on future copy attempts simply ignore those that haven't changed.

Comment: Just wanted to rsync files who's modified time changes.  I think that is the default along with size.  But I was unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I understanding your question correctly? 'Modified time' is one of the default criteria, when `rsync` decides if the copy should be updated or not.

From `man rsync`

> Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check"
>   algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size
>   or in last-modified time.  Any changes in  the  other preserved 
>   attributes  (as requested by options) are made on the destination file
>   directly when the quick check indicates that the file’s data does not
>   need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to runthe following:

```
rsync -an /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Then verify that only the desired files are going to be transferred. Once you have verified this run the above command without the `-n` flag and you will accomplish your goal. As pointed out by user roaima there is another flag that will accomplish your goal and that is `-t`. Using the `-a` flag is equivalent to  `-rlptgoD`. Read all about `rsync` usage [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

An alternative way would be to use the command from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/538778/458184):

> ```
>  find /path/to/source -file -mtime +3 -exec rsync {} /path/to/destination \;
> ```

So you use `find` to locate all files at a given `$SOURCE` that have a modified date as of 3 days ago. You can change `-mtime +3` to however many days back you want to go. Once you have identified all files at the given `$SOURCE` you then execute `rsync` (with whatever desired options) to your `$DESTINATION`.

Comment: Simplest would be `rsync -a` (no `find`) and let the utility do what it does well. But it really depends on the reason for the OP to want to limit by times in the first place.

Comment: @roaima You are right, upon review this answer is pretty sloppy. I use super specific flags with `rsync` depending on the context so I forgot that default `rsync` does on a practical standpoint what OP is asking. The find command is if they need to look at files modified at specific times. I will clean this up.