# rsync on file unmodifed since 2 hours only?

Tags: rsync

I have an app on a remote server that produces new binary files roughly every 2 hours.
Every 6 minutes, if there is new data, files are updated. They are closed after 19 appending, which means that if there is new data in between each new 6 minutes, they are closed after 1hr 54 minutes.

They are parquet files:

- parquet files can be appended till they are not closed, which is what my app does.
- parquet files cannot be opened till they are closed

Filenames are in the form s below. The last digit being the timestamp when the file is created. This timestamp is not updated afterward.

```
my-data-1602915797.parquet
my-data-1609890860.parquet
my-other-d-1609990998.parquet
my-other-d-1610000010.parquet
```

Once complete files have been written, and once they have been safely copied locally (on my 8To local hard drive), I have to remove them from remote (only 160Go hard disk on remote)
The app is producing between 4 and 5Go of data per day.

I plan to launch this file transfer once a month.

So, I would like to transfer only those which are closed.
To select them, I could use with ssh.

```
# IP address is a dummy address ;)
ssh root@180.18.17.91 "find /root/my_data -name *.parquet -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +180"
```

Then pipe this into `rsync`.

But then, I could spot [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489550/rsync-based-on-modified-time) where it is said that there might solution by using
`rsync -a`.

Looking into rsync man page, I have not been able to spot out how this parameter can answer this need.
Please, anyone to help understanding?

Thanks for any feedback, much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `lsof` to get a list of open files. That list you can then pass to `--exclude` of  rsync.

Comment: @roaima : full post completed, you should have the full picture of the situation now ;)
the app ony use the timestamp in the filename when the file is created. This timestamp is not updated afterward, only the file content is.

Comment: @Lucas thanks for the tip, I will definitely have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rsync` to copy the files as you have described, and to remove them once they have been successfully copied:

```
rsync --dry-run -avz --remove-source-files root@180.18.17.91:'$(find /root/my_data -maxdepth 1 -name "*.parquet" -type f -mmin +30)' /my/destination
```

Please notice that,

- I have used single quotes rather than double quotes to surround the evaluated command `$( find ... )` so that it is executed in the context of the remote server rather than the local one
- I have quoted `*.parquet` to stop the shell trying to match it to one (or more) of your parquet files
- I have reduced the delay from 180 minutes after last update to just 30 minutes (you say that the latest file gets updated every six minutes, so 30 is more than sufficient)
- I have used `-z` to compress the data stream across the network connection. Even with pre-compressed data this will help a little
- The directory `/my/destination` is the local directory into which the parquet files will be moved

I strongly recommend you try it with `--dry-run` enabled to check what is going to happen, and then remove that parameter when you are comfortable with the intended result

Add `--progress` if you want to watch in real time to see how the each file's transfer is progressing. Do not use `-P` or `--partial` here.

I should point out that there is no easy way to identify files that have been "closed". You could write some code to use `lsof` or maybe something from the `inotify` family. What I've done here is to rely on the application writing to the current file within 30 minutes of its last update, so that the OS can automatically update the file modification time accordingly. If your application fiddles around with the file modification time (metadata, not the filename) then this will break.

The cleanest solution would be to modify your application to create its files as `*.parquet.tmp` and then rename them to the corresponding `*.parquet` when it's finished writing to them. (This would allow you to guarantee that only `*parquet` files were completed, and thus appropriate for copying.) But I do appreciate that this may not be possible.

Comment: Hi @roima, I really appreciate your educational answer, very informative. I have delved in the direction of lsof and will post as an answer the 2 lines I have come up with as well. I can only recommend your way of doing however :). Roima, I have one question in your answer. Please could you clarify "I have quoted *.parquet to stop the shell trying to match it to one (or more) of your parquet files"      I want it to match the parquet files if I want them to be filtered in, so I don't understand this comment.  thanks for your help, bests

Comment: Also, in the solution I am myself posting, you may notice I have removed the `-z` parameter from `rsync`. parquet file content is already compressed with `brotli` algo, level 6.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` to generate a file list for `rsync` will work if you really can't copy files unless they have been closed.

You can also just use `rsync` as is. It will copy open partial files but why does that matter. After they change, `rsync` will notice that they have been updated and sync them.

Comment: Hi, thank for your comment.
There are 2 reasons I am reluctant to copy partial files:
1- I need to remove complete files from remote once they have been copied.
2- Not closed file cannot be open, this raises an error. But for this, I am ok, I could work out a way to catch the error in my python program that post-process these files locally.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring proposal to use `lsof` from @Lucas, I have come up with these 2 lines.

Formatting the output of `lsof` command into a clean filename list turns out rather complex, but this way enables to make sure only closed files are retained, whatever change there can be in the app that generates the files.

```bsh
ssh root@"$RMT_IP" "lsof +D "$RMT_PATH_DATA" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f9 | tail -n +2 | grep '.parquet$' | xargs -n 1 basename"  > "$OPEN_FILES"
rsync --dry-run -avv --remove-source-files --exclude-from="$OPEN_FILES" root@"$RMT_IP":"$RMT_PATH_DATA"/*.txt "$TEMP_LOC_PATH"
```

-vv parameter makes `rsync` detailing files that are skipped. On my test files, I could check the list from `$OPEN_FILES` is correctly read.